# How to deal with high load server losing connection to MySQL (Node, Express, Sequelize)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

On a reasonably loaded server (roughly 200 requests per minute) that connects to MySQL to update a record using `Node`, `Express` and `Sequelize` how should database outages be dealt with?

With a standard setup with each request updating a record in the database when we lose the database connection, each express connection is put on hold and eventually times out as expected.

If MySQL comes back in a short period of time the process recovers but if the database is down for extended periods of time >5mins things go a bit crazy.

Even after the database comes back online the requests are still not processed and either `ECONNRESET` or `ETIMEDOUT` errors are returned from mysql/sequelize. At this point the only way to clear this is to kill the process and restart.

Updates to the database are performed by `Sequelize` using in this example the `upsert` command as shown in this (simplified) example:

```
model
  .upsert(ak)
  .then(() => {
    res.send('ok')
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    res.send('fail')
  })
```

My question is how should the code deal with this situation so that express does not build up hundreds of pending connections?

Comment: Perhaps start with finding the reason why connections to the database get lost in the first place?

Comment: That would be ideal but is on the ops side, not on the dev side so not something I have much input into :) I would like to make sure things are handled properly in the code so that it a connection loss occurs it can recover properly